# Fix Broken File Permissions On Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, permissions

I have a VPS running Ubuntu 16.04

I changed the owner of the root directory (`/`) recursively to root.

- I was young and stupid (this happened about an hour ago but never mind).
- Various things don't work correctly now including a website in the `/var/www/html` folder.
- I searched far and wide for a solution but only found either OS-specific instructions which didn't work for me or the instruction to reinstall which, as you might guess, is not what I want to do.
- I'm looking for a way to restore all file and folder permissions to what they were before without individually finding and changing them.
- If someone provides a link with instructions which might not be understood by a noob who goes around changing permissions recursively in the root of a linux server then please explain or simplify what the link says.

Thank you all in advance and I hope this issue gets solved as soon as possible.

-user9123